# Israel-Turkey or Turkey-Israel ties?

Tags: dashes

I recall back in college the teacher once noting that there is a rule for that. I've checked google and found both are used. Is there a rule for that?

Comment: If you are an Israeli citizen, you use "Israel-Turkey" and if you are a Turkish, you use "Turkey-Israel".

Comment: And if I'm non?

Comment: Which side will you take if they fight or which country do you hate more? Pick one.

Comment: There's no particular order. Just use that order which is easy to speak in.

Comment: @Rathony I'm quite sure it's not as straightforward as that. One hears of an *Anglo-American* initiative or a *Franco-German* agreement but seldom the other ways around.

Comment: @WS2 I disagree. If you use it the wrong way especially for politically sensitive countries such as Israel, China, Japan, Korea, etc, it can create a diplomatic issue. I think Anglo-American and Franco-German are just idiomatic usages.

Comment: @NVZ Do you use "China-India" cooperation / relationship / treaty, etc. in India?

Comment: @Rathony I've never had to. Usually we start with our own country name. But speaking of relationships between two other countries, I just use the way that I find easier to speak.

Comment: @Rathony On second thought, I see how people tend to mention that country name first which they have an emotional attachment to.

Comment: @NVZ I am not saying it is the strict rule, but let's say Japan and Korea talk about "U.S. vs China", it is very obvious which country Japan and Korea will put first.

Comment: @Rathony I've always mentioned "India-Pakistan" cricket match, and not the other way around. Maybe I'll ask my Pakistani friends how they say it.

Comment: @WS2 - "Anglo-American" is that way because "Americo" is not a common adjective.  Likewise "Germano".

Comment: @HotLicks Interestingly *Anglo* and *Franco* are mostly only used in this context - though sometimes you will see a reference to *Anglo values*, or *Anglo concerns* etc.

Comment: @WS2 - Yep, and there are one or two others, such as *Sino*.  How such adjectival prefixes got created is one for the etymologists, but some are "natural" and others would be quite strained, in terms of how they roll off the tongue.